# Is the identity function the only order-preserving isomorphism between a linearly-ordered set and itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

It is well known that

**the identity function is the only order-preserving isomorphism between a well-ordered set and itself**.

My question is: what is an counterexample to this with a linearly (and thus not well-ordered) set ?

**EDIT**

My trivial  questions has a continuation: why there is no faithful functor from $\mathbf{Lin}$ of linearly ordered sets and order preserving injective mappings to well-ordered sets and the order preserving injective mappings by the 2 examples of iso-rigidness of WOS and iso-nonrigidness of $\mathbf{Lin}$ ?

Comment: $x\mapsto x+1$ on $(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$

Comment: @user85667 Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: Take $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ as above and $1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ the identity. Assume that $F$ is a functor between those categories. Assume $F(f)\neq F(1_{\mathbb{Z}})$, since otherwise $F$ is already non-faithful. Then $F(f)$ is not onto. However, $F(f)F(f^{-1})=F(ff^{-1})=F(1_{\mathbb{Z}})=1_{F(\mathbb{Z})}$ shows that $F(f)$ is onto.

Comment: @user85667 Too fast. Why "**Then $F(f)$ is not onto.**" ?

Comment: If $F(f)$ is onto, and since it is also injective and order-preserving, it would be $1_{F(\mathbb{Z})}$, by the result in bold text in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: your edit, the point is that if $\lambda$ is a well-order then there is exactly one **invertible** morphism from $\lambda$ to itself, but something like $\mathbb{Z}$ has many invertible self-morphisms (e.g. $x\mapsto x+1$). Now by definition a faithful functor is injective on morphisms and sends identity morphisms to identity morphisms, so there's no "room" to send $\mathbb{Z}$ to a well-ordering in a faithful way.

More generally, if $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is faithful and every object in $\mathcal{D}$ has no non-identity invertible self-morphisms then every object in $\mathcal{C}$ must also have no non-identity invertible self-morphisms. Note that this isn't really any different from the fact that if $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ is faithful and every object in $\mathcal{D}$ has at most $17$ self-morphisms, then every object in $\mathcal{C}$ must also have at most $17$ self-morphisms, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly not true. For example, $x \mapsto x+c$ is an order isomorphism for any real constant $c$, and $x \mapsto dx$ is an order isomorphism for any positive real constant $d$.